# Call array on array

Tags: arrays, swift, random

I am trying to randomize an Array and when I have that Array randomize a value from that Array:

```
class Board {

    var animalArray:[String] = ["beerArray", "duckArray"]
    var bearArray:[String] = ["bear", "bear1", "bear2"]
    var duckArray:[String] = ["duck", "duck1"]
    var chosenArray:String
    var chosenImage:String

    init () {
        self.chosenArray = ""
        self.chosenImage = ""

    }

    func randomArray () {

        // Randomize a number
        var firstRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))
        var secondRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(1)) 

        // Construct a string with the random numbers
        self.chosenArray = self.animalArray[firstRandomNumber]
        self.chosenImage = self.chosenArray[secondRandomNumber] //this part doesn't work

        print(chosenArray)
        print(chosenImage)

        }

}
```

So I do get a random Array in the chosenArray that is working. When I try to access the Array that was randomized I can't get the value from that Array via a randomizer. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What language is this? Maybe add a tag?

Comment: The code is in "swift"

Comment: your chosenArray is defined as an empty string. Is that supposed to be like that? Pretty sure you can't access characters of string like that anyway.

Comment: Even if I predefine it with a value, I can't get the result I am hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `chosenArray` needs to be of type Array.
Also take care of your random numbers, because your arrays have different sizes.

```
class Board {


var bearArray:[String] = ["bear", "bear1", "bear2"]
var duckArray:[String] = ["duck", "duck1"]
//animal array is a nested array (two dimensional)
var animalArray:[[String]]
//as the name says chosenArray must also be of type array
var chosenArray:[String]
var chosenImage:String

init () {
    self.chosenArray = []
    self.chosenImage = ""
    self.animalArray = [beerArray, duckArray]

}

func randomArray () {

    // choose the array
    var firstRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
    self.chosenArray = animalArray[firstRandomNumber]

    //choose random element from chosen array
    var secondRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(chosenArray.count))) 
    self.chosenImage = self.chosenArray[secondRandomNumber]

    print(chosenArray)
    print(chosenImage)

    }

 }
```

Edit: Read more about the Array-type [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID450)

Comment: Great hendra this really helped! Still learning the basics as you can see. How come the variables bearArray and duckArray need to be outside the class Board? When I leave them in it says instance member ''bearArray'' cannot be used on type Board.

Comment: Yes, keep up learning :)
I edited my answer. You have to move the initialization of `animalArray` to `init()`, because you try to access a member of `self` before `self` is initialized.